# How to find the derivative of one expression with respect to another expression

Tags: derivatives

I've been trying to find a way to take the derivative of one expression with respect to another expression, but I can't think of any obvious way to do it, and I'm not even sure where I should start.

For example, would it be possible to find the derivative of $x^6$ with respect to $x^2$, or the derivative of $\sin(x)$ with respect to $cos(x)$?

Comment: You could do something like: $f(x) = x^6 = (x^2)^3 \rightarrow f'(x) = 6x^5 = 3(x^2)^2(2x) = 6x^5$ (the latter is using the product and chain rule).

Answer (score 10):

If one knows the chain rule, $$\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx},$$ then one may solve for $$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{dg}{dx}}.$$ For your one of your examples, $\frac{d\sin x}{d\cos x}$, we may compute this to be  $$\frac{d\sin x}{d\cos x}=\frac{\frac{d \sin x}{dx}}{\frac{d\cos x}{dx}}=\frac{\cos x}{-\sin x}=-\cot x.$$

One should also note that we *should* define the derivative of $f$ with respect to $g$ as the following limit:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}.$$

Comment: The example that I posted was "the derivative of sin(x) with respect to cos(x)", and not "the derivative of sin(x) divided by the derivative of cos(x)", so I'm not sure if this solution is correct.

Comment: My solution is correct, it just is not the example you posted. At any rate I edited it so it is your example.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{d\ x^6}{d\ x^2} 
= \frac{\frac{d\ x^6}{d\ x}}{\frac{d\ x^2}{d\ x}} 
= \frac{6x^5}{2x} 
= 3x^4
$$

Comment: The above is the easiest and simplest way to solve the question

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You computed correctly another example of the general case of the chain rule, as described by [Baby Dragon](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/491205). To make your answer more readable, please add some text describing it. By the way, the equations are easier to read when we use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Baby Dragon's answer which works for the general case, here is another approach that works for the trig case.

Let $z = \cos x$.

$\frac{d}{d \cos x} \sin x=\frac{d}{dz}\sqrt{1-z^2}=\frac{-z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\frac{-\cos x}{\sin x}.$