# Differentiate $y=x$ with respect to $x^2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $y=x$. Differentiate $y$ with respect to $x^2$.

My intuition tells me to go down a substitution route here. So, let $u=x^2~~ \Leftrightarrow~~x=\sqrt{u}$, then what we are looking to find is simply

$$\frac{d}{du}\sqrt{u}$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$$
as $\sqrt{u}=x$,
$$\frac{d}{dx^2}~x=\frac{1}{2x}$$

is this approach/solution correct, or is there something fundamentally wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Your solution is correct, you can find other way to do this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491192/how-to-find-the-derivative-of-one-expression-with-respect-to-another-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct.

Alternatively, from the Chain Rule, $$y=x\implies y^2=x^2\implies \frac{dy^2}{d(x^2)}=\frac{d}{d(x^2)}(x^2)\implies 2y\frac{dy}{d(x^2)}=1\implies \boxed{\frac{dy}{dx^2}=\frac1{2y}=\frac1{2x}}$$

Note that this method is used very often in statistics (e.g. maximum likelihood estimates for the variance since we estimate $\sigma^2$ rather than $\sigma$; hence we prefer to differentiate the former).

Comment: I think you missed out the two in the denominator of your final fraction, but your method makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Set $z=x^2$. Then $x= \sqrt z$ and:
$$\frac{d}{d(x^2)}y=\frac{d}{d(x^2)}x=    \frac{d}{dz}\sqrt z=   \frac{1}{2 \sqrt z}=  \frac{1}{2x}  $$

Comment: (-1) This is exactly what OP did. There's no point in only rewriting what the OP has tried.