# Limit definition of derivative of one function with respect to another

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Then the derivative of $f$ is denoted $f'$ and is defined by the mapping: $$f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Now suppose we also have the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Would it  then be the case that "the derivative of $f$ with respect to $g$" (if this is a proper notion at all) is denoted $f'(g)$ and is defined by the mapping: $$f'\left(g(a)\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f\left(g(x)\right)-f(\left(g(a)\right)}{g(x)-g(a)}?$$

Comment: [This question might have an answer for you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491192/how-to-find-the-derivative-of-one-expression-with-respect-to-another-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, given that $f(x)$ is differentiable in $b=g(a)$ and $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f\left(g(x)\right)-f(\left(g(a)\right)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\lim_{y\rightarrow b}\frac{f(y)-f(b)}{y-b}=f'(b)=f'(g(a))$$

Comment: @Subhajit above linked to [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/491205/547493) which states instead, "One should also note that we *should* define the derivative of $f$ with respect to $g$ as the following limit: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}."$$ I think you and I are correct but do you know why that other person might have thought differently?

Comment: @dtcm840 The two are equivalent under the given hypotesis.