# How do we find the derivative of a multivariate expression wrt another multivariate expression?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have $f(\theta,b) = 1 - \theta x - b$.  I want to find $$\frac{df(\theta,b)}{d[\frac{1-b}{\theta}]}$$

i.e. the change in $f$ wrt $\frac{1-b}{\theta}$.  In the language of limits,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0, a \to 0} \frac{f(\theta + h, b + a) - f(\theta, b)}{\frac{1 - b - a}{\theta + h} - \frac{1 - b}{\theta}}
$$

I saw this [How to find the derivative of one expression with respect to another expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491192/how-to-find-the-derivative-of-one-expression-with-respect-to-another-expression)

which made me think I could try
$$\frac{df(\theta,b)}{d[\frac{1-b}{\theta}]} = \frac{\frac{df(\theta,b)}{d\theta}}{\frac{d[\frac{1-b}{\theta}]}{d\theta}} = \frac{\theta^2 x}{1 - b}$$

But if I do the same strategy wrt the other variable, I get
$$\frac{df(\theta,b)}{d[\frac{1-b}{\theta}]} = \frac{\frac{df(\theta,b)}{db}}{\frac{d[\frac{1-b}{\theta}]}{db}} = \theta$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: What does the expression $df(\theta,b)/dg(\theta,b)$ even *mean*?!? What exactly is it that you want to compute, and why?

Comment: I believe I got the right answer below, but I want the derivative of f wrt infinitesimal changes in $\frac{1-b}{\theta}$.  Is this not well-defined?

Comment: Apologies if my notation was nonstandard or unclear.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  If f isn't shown to be a function of $(1-b)/\theta$ then this expression has no meaning.

Comment: As I recall, I think that I always solved this sort of thing via differentials and Jacobians.  If you want I will try to write it up.  It leads to obvious results but requires setup.  There are pitfalls but can usually be done.

Answer (score -1):

The thing about decomposing $\frac{df(\theta,b)}{dg(\theta,b)}$ into two separate expressions, and then calculate the product is a fundamentally flawed way to calculate multivariate derivatives. It does often work, but not all the time. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906241/when-not-to-treat-dy-dx-as-a-fraction-in-single-variable-calculus) article goes into more detail about it.

To respond to your question, with

$$g(\theta,b)=\frac{1-b}{\theta}$$
we know that
$$\theta=\frac{1-b}{g(\theta,b)}$$

Therefore, we plug it into $f$ and get

$$f(\theta,b)=1-\frac{1-b}{g(\theta,b)} x-b$$

And so,

$$\frac{df(\theta,b)}{dg(\theta,b)} = \frac{(1-b)x}{g(\theta,b)^2}$$

which when plugging in for $g(\theta,b)$, gets us the answer you found first,
$$\frac{\theta^2 x}{1-b}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this solution.  How come you can do a substitution for $\theta$ but not for $b$?  Intuitively if $(1-b)/\theta$ is changing, then so is $b$, right?

Comment: One of the requirements of using the method you have proposed, is that the function is invertible. Because your functions use two variables, the functions need to be invertible for both variables for it to work for both variables. If you take the derivative with respect to $b$, you are losing information, as $\theta^2$, is non-invertible ($\sqrt(\theta) = \theta, -\theta$). When taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$, because no information is lost (i.e. $b$ has no even power), you get the desired outcome.